# How to use vue-router in Laravel8 project?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm, laravel-8

I tried to do the Investory management project  with **laravel7 +VueJs + RestAPIs** , I have tried also with Laravel8 following given steps with

```sh
composer require laravel/ui
php artisan ui vue --auth
npm install
npm install vue-router
php artisan migrate 
npm run dev
```

then I am getting this error , where the instruction have shown, he has created 2 component Login and Register and after all stuff Login page in comming in home page with Vue-router but in my case nothing happen , please help , the error is here

> npm ERR! node_modules/vue
>
> npm ERR! dev vue@"^2.6.12" from the root project
>
> npm ERR!
>
> npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
>
> npm ERR! peer vue@"^3.2.0" from vue-router@4.0.15
>
> npm ERR! node_modules/vue-router
>
> npm ERR! vue-router@"4" from the root project

Comment: You need to be in the root of your project when you run those commands, and have a valid package.json (run `npm init` to create).

Comment: Looks like `vue-router@4` requires `vue@3` while you have `vue@2` installed. Try a lower version for `vue-router`

Comment: Thanks a lot !! , but now I am getting new error, after installing vue-route@3

Comment: @brombeer new error like  [webpack-cli] Error: Cannot find module 'webpack/lib/rules/DescriptionDataMatcherRulePlugin'
Require stack:
- E:\My Projects\Laravel\Other Projects\Laravel8_Inventory\node_modules\vue-loader\lib\plugin-webpack5.js
- E:\My Projects\Laravel\Other Projects\Laravel8_Inventory\node_modules\vue-loader\lib\plugin.js       
- E:\My Projects\Laravel\Other Projects\Laravel8_Inventory\node_modules\vue-loader\lib\index.js

Comment: @brombeer E:\My Projects\Laravel\Other Projects\Laravel8_Inventory\node_modules\webpack-cli\lib\webpack-cli.js 
- E:\My Projects\Laravel\Other Projects\Laravel8_Inventory\node_modules\webpack-cli\lib\bootstrap.js   
- E:\My Projects\Laravel\Other Projects\Laravel8_Inventory\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\cli.js
- E:\My Projects\Laravel\Other Projects\Laravel8_Inventory\node_modules\webpack\bin\webpack.js

Answer (score 1):

Same problem.

npm ERR! code ERESOLVE

npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree

npm ERR!

npm ERR! While resolving: undefined@undefined

npm ERR! Found: vue@2.6.14

npm ERR! node_modules/vue

npm ERR!   dev vue@"^2.6.14" from the root project

npm ERR!

npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:

npm ERR! peer vue@"^3.2.0" from vue-router@4.0.15

npm ERR! node_modules/vue-router

npm ERR!   vue-router@"*" from the root project

npm ERR!

npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry

npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps

npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.

npm ERR!

npm ERR! See C:\Users\Mithun\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

Comment: please let me know if u find any solution , fade up with this ...@Khaled Ahmed Mithun